# Is there a version of contextlib.contextmanager for classes in python?

Tags: python, class, contextmanager

Using generators as the building blocks for context managers is a nice approach because it keeps all the state in one place. For example:

```
@contextlib.contextmanager
def manager():
    state = get_state() 
    try:
        yield f(state)
    except Exception:
        handle(state)
    finally:
        cleanup(state)
```

However, a common patterm is the following:

```
class Client():
   ...

with Client() as c:
    c.blah()
```

this does not lend itself to the use contextmanagers because Client calls `__init__`.

Is  there a way of defining a class, but still using generators to define the `__enter__` and exit code?

Comment: I don't think you need a separate version. You can just create the instant of `Client` in the context manager, or pass a pre-made instance as an argument.

Comment: There's no requirement for the object to be created by the `with` statement; `f = Client(); with f as c: ...` works the same.

Comment: @chepner The thing is that client is also a class.... one approach I've thought of is using `with Client.open() as x:` - having `open` be a class method. I suspect other people who look at the code would moan at me if I did that...

Comment: I don't see what that has to do with anything. The fact that you often see things like `with open(...) as f:` is just because a file-like object implements its `__enter__` method to return the object itself. `with` statements don't have to create an object; they only have to call an object's `__enter__` method.

Comment: If I understand correctly you can't `contextlib.contextmanager`  while using `__enter__`?

Comment: `contextmanager` just returns an instance of a [pre-defined class](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/contextlib.py#L123) that uses a generator to define its `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. You could, for example, just write `m = manager(); with m as f: ...` It doesn't matter if `manager` is defined using a decorated function or a class with explicitly defined `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.